# how to change screen of same window opened in C++ with createwindowex()

Tags: c++, winapi

My question is edited as below

I have a main window then I have menu bar where I have defined certain functions. For Each function I want to open a new window.

But since I have (more than) 5 Operations, I do not want to open new window for each option, instead if if can happen in one same window. In the attached figure, you can see the initial design layout that I have made.

Note the three different options in Menu, Process, ADC parameters, Scanning Parameters
[image]

(note that behind each function , there is a complete different set of control etc. for hardware communication).

Comment: I cannot understand this. Do you want to create a new window on a different monitor? Or do you want to move a window to a different monitor?

Comment: I mean, I have created one window with CreateWindowEx() command, now I have menus in menu bar -> When I select one option in that same window, the contents of window change without opening another window...

I hope i explain all right

Comment: No. I still cannot understand.

Comment: You need to edit your question and explain better what you're trying to do and what you've already tried. If it's a problem with English, perhaps get some local assistance.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please see if you can assist

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that for each function there is a complete different set of controls, it is better to design 3 different dialog forms and use them separately.

One way is to design the dialogs in the Resource View, use single dialog box containing 3 [Property Sheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774538%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can hide the tabs of the property pages if you want so that you have one dialog box with 3 different forms.

Also another way is that you can use [Document-View-Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x1xy43a.aspx) of MFC (Microsoft Foundation Classes) and create 3 different views derived from CFormView. CFormView takes in the dialog template id (designed using Resource View).

Whenever the user chooses a function from the menu, you can activate a different view. Since you are using views instead of modal dialog boxes, it will appear as if the same view is being updated. But internally, you will have 3 separate document/views handling the processing.